Material UI offline docs
Is there a way to download and read MUI documentation offline ?
I know I can build MUI website from source code using their github repository but my laptop barely runs itself and when I tried doing this it lags so bad it just becomes unusable, isn't there a better way to do this ?

I'm not sure if I got this right, but you could clone the MUI repo into your computer and read through the markdown files or explore the docs app.
MUI Docs app on github
